# One particular UID causes very slow performance

Tags: centos, performance, dd, uid

One of our accounts on a CentOS 7 machine experienced very slow disk read/write. 
I started looking into this because the 1007 user on this machine
ran `wget` much slower than other user/machines.

```
id
uid=1007(test.dd) gid=1001(xxx) groups=1001(xxx),10(wheel)

ulimit -m 100000000; sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test1.img bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync 
[sudo] password for test.dd:
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 25.6939 s, 41.8 MB/s
```

1007 seems to be the culprit here since I deleted the user and recreated another using the same UID, or changed an existing user to the same UID, and got the same result. Also I made sure no other users under `/etc/passwd` have UID or GID = 1007.

It turns out all other users have 4× the speed under the same command.

```
id
uid=1008(yyy) gid=1001(xxx) groups=1001(xxx),10(wheel),994(docker)

ulimit -m 100000000; sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test1.img bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync 
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 6.61231 s, 162 MB/s
```

What could possibly have gone wrong?

Update: after replacing `of=/tmp/test1.img` with `of=/dev/null`,
I get a similar performance gap between 1007 and other users:

```
id
uid=1007(test.dd) gid=1001(xxx) groups=1001(xxx),10(wheel)

ulimit -m 100000000; sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 4.31788 s, 249 MB/s
```

```
id
uid=1008(yyy) gid=1001(xxx) groups=1001(xxx),10(wheel),994(docker)

ulimit -m 100000000; sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 0.309438 s, 3.5 GB/s
```

Update 2: after changing `/dev/zero` to `/tmp/test1.img`, the two users get the same speed finally. So looks like something about the `/dev` mount point is treating user 1007 and other users differently. Any clue on why that may be the case?

Comment: This has to be an issue with your testing methodology. There's nothing that would make a specific user slower. Did you make sure you dropped the page cache before tests?

Comment: @forest Thanks. I just tried and succeeded with " sudo sh -c ' echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches ' ", but still got
ulimit -m 100000000; dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test1.img bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 27.1012 s, 39.6 MB/s

Comment: Is `/tmp` mounted as tmpfs?

Comment: @forest df -h indeed reveals the following mount point "tmpfs            26G     0   26G   0% /run/user/1007".  I will umount it and try again. Meanwhile could you shed some light on why it can slow disk down? Thanks!

Comment: Well if it was running as tmpfs then you know that it's not the disk itself that is slow. Also doing `bs=1G` is highly inefficient. The block size is usually best at around 256k or so. Btw, you did `sudo dd` which means that both commands are running as euid 0.

Comment: @forest Indeed there was also a "tmpfs /run/user/0" entry under "df -h". I removed both, and ran dd command without sudo, but still got about 40 MB/s under the account with uid 1007. I started looking into this because the 1007 user on this machine ran wget much slower than other user/machines.

Comment: Just replaced /tmp/test1.img with dev/test1.img and got similar speed: 45MB/sec. Maybe need to replace /dev/zero with something else but not sure how.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124297/discussion-between-john-jiang-and-forest).